# Why img:hover doesn't work here?

Tags: html, css

I'm hidding an anchor by setting `visibility:hidden`.
On image hover, I set the anchor visibility to `visible`, but the anchor doesn't appear on image hover.

Not sure what's going wrong in the snippet.

```
  #image{
    width :240px;
    height :190px;
  }
  #image:hover #link{
    visibility : visible;
  }
  #link{
    visibility : hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 170px;
  }
```

```
<img id="image" src="images/Goals.jpg" alt="Goals" />
<a href="http://google.com" id="link" target="_blank">Goals Analysis App Link</a>
```

The visibility issue got resolved once applying appropriate selector. But now, when i hover on the link, it starts flickering. Any hints on this ?

check the snippet  http://jsbin.com/yiqek/3/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#link` is an adjacent sibling of `#image` so you need to write

```
  #image:hover + #link{
    visibility : visible;
  }
```

`+` is the adjacent sibling selector

`A + B` matches `B` when is the immediate sibling of `A`

Comment: It works. But now, when i hover on the link it filckers ! http://jsbin.com/yiqek/3/edit . Any hint ?

Comment: of course if you hover the link then `#image:hover` is no longer applied. You should apply instead the `:hover` rule to a parent of both the image and the link: e.g. http://jsbin.com/vakusogu/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

You need [adjacent siblings selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) for this:

```
 #image:hover  + #link{
    visibility : visible;
  }
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/qihosaze/2/)

Answer (score 1):

please add the code to the question body as well. Anyways, you wrote this:

```
#image:hover  #link{
  visibility : visible;
}
```

Which will make `#link` inside of `<img id="image">` visible. Since you can have no links inside of an image, this is making no sense. The link is the direct sibling of the image, so you can do this:

```
#image:hover + #link{
  visibility : visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
#image:hover #link{
visibility : visible;
  }
```

Use like this..

```
#image:hover + #link{
visibility : visible;
 }
```